# Oracle Apex: Setting Page Items using SQL - Not adding to Session

Tags: oracle-apex

I don't see the values in Session when using the Debug, but the page items are rendering:

[image]

I am setting the Source using a SQL Expression:

[image]

And I know the query is working, as the page item is rendering out for P2_KPI_NAME on the page.

Why are they not being added to Session once calculated?

Comment: Are you submitting the form? When you submit the form the items will be saved in the session. If you are using AJAX you need to save the items manually in the session. Like this

BEGIN
    APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('my_item','myvalue');
END;

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you *see* it doesn't mean it is in session state.

For testing purposes, create a button on that page which will perform SUBMIT. Push it, and then check Session tab in Debug output.

Comment: Why should I have to Submit, if I am calculating the page Item, and specifying that the value should always replace the item in Session state (see screenshot).  Sort of implies it will put the value into Session State. I tried to use the Post Calculation to do an APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE but it didn't like it.

Comment: Why? For testing purposes.

Comment: The question is really why an option "Always replace value in Session State", doesnt replace the value in Session state at the point it is calculated?  The option doesn't say "Always replace value in Session State (but only after a subsequence Submit)"

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dynamic action on change of :P2_KPI_ID in which you set your second item using PL/SQL (remember to add P2_KPI_ID to Item to Submit aswell as your second item as a Item to Return).
"Always replace value in Session State" sets the items value when its getting rendered.The item itself is not refreshed when your :P2_KPI_ID is set and therefor its value is not set automatically.

Comment: So its a bit misleading to say the Source calculation will always replace any value in Session State, as it obviously doesnt commit the value at the point of calculation into Session?

Comment: this replacement option has a different use case and the wording can misleading at first I agree. Fortunately we have another option for your requirement using dynamic actions though

Comment: I am passing in an ID from the previous page.  Then when the target page is loaded, I am using this ID to pull back the individual page items.  Ideally they would be better in session for debugging as there are a lot of them.  Another option I guess is to use a Fetch Row process to populate the page items, using the primary key...I am assuming this would place the page items into session, I would need to set the source to Database Column I am thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the result of a performance optimization used during page rendering. Most of the time we think of session state, we think of persisted session state, i.e. the state in the session table.

However, in-memory session state is often used by APEX when rendering a page to avoid the overhead of running DML against the session table when it usually doesn't need to be there anyway (the next submit will overwrite it).

See this old, but still relevant, post to learn more:
http://c2anton.blogspot.com/2008/12/oracle-application-express-apex-three.html